# Virtual Pascal GetDate returns Type mismatch?

Tags: pascal

I'm trying to port a DOS Pascal app to Windows using Virtual Pascal and working fairly well until this simple procedure:

```
PROCEDURE SysDate(VAR dt : datetype);
VAR
A,B,C,D : WORD;
BEGIN
  GETDATE(A,B,C,D);
  DT.YEAR := A;
  DT.MONTH := B;
  DT.DAY := C;
END;
```

caused this error:

```
Error 26: Type mismatch
  GETDATE(A,B,C,D);
...........^
```

Any ideas what may be causing it?  I searched the source for virtual pascal and the dos unit is the only thing defining `GetDate()` and defines all the variables as `WORD` as it should.

Comment: For kicks I tried a `LongInt` and it took it but saw no reference in source code that reference `GetDate` with a `LongInt`

Comment: The concrete size of integer types in Virtual Pascal depends on whether you run in "use16" or "use32" mode. Depending on that mode the type `Word` can be either 16bit or 32bit.

Comment: Ah-ha, now I see the `Use32` requirement in the manual, not sure what `{&Use32+}` state is, I'll have to look in to that.  Thanks.